# How to publish the application that using GPS on devices with GPS and not using GPS on devices without GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I have the application in Google Play. Today supported 5215 devices. The application has in `AndroidManifest.xml` the following:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Obviously, in Google Play Console I see that features are included

```
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
```

and permissions are included

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

The problem that our customer has device without GPS, and the application isn't available in Google Play on this device.

I've read on [developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) that I can add `<uses-feature>` tag with `android:required="false"` parameter. So I added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.GPS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.NETWORK" android:required="false"/>
```

Nothing changed, the same 5215 devices. But if I delete request for `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, 5856 devices are available (added 641).

What's wrong? How to publish the app for devices with and without GPS together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pretty sure this is what you need

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

`GPS` is different than `gps`

Comment: It strange, but it works: the value 'android.hardware.location.GPS' I've copied from table in Developer Console. Thank you.

Comment: IIRC whenever you use the `uses-feature` in the manifest everything is always lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure but it seem like if you request

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

It enables the gps settings to true no-matter what you specify. The only surest way to find out is to ignore the numbers of supported devices for the moment and  publish your app in play store with the manifest that you have shown here and try downloading the app in devices with and without gps chipset.